# Why are attributes not passed in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, netcdf, netcdf4

I have written a script to extract spatial and temporal subsets from netCDF datasets from the IPCC. The following piece of script works just fine:

```
import numpy
import netCDF4
import datetime

drs_name    = ['C:\\pr_Amon_MPI-ESM-MR_rcp45_r2i1p1_200601-210012.nc']
cdf_dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(drs_name[0])
cdf_time    = cdf_dataset.variables['time']

date_start  = 2006
time_start  = datetime.datetime(date_start,1,1,0,0,0)

sbset_time_loindex = netCDF4.date2index(time_start,cdf_time,
                                    calendar = cdf_calendar,
                                    select='nearest')
```

The variable 'time' from the cdf_dataset has attributes and when I write "cdf_time" as above they are carried to it. Here is a simple print output for "cdf_time":

```
cdf_time is : <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
bounds: time_bnds
units: days since 1850-1-1 00:00:00
calendar: proleptic_gregorian
axis: T
long_name: time
standard_name: time
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1140,)
filling off
```

In this specific case it is the attribute "units" which is then required by "netCDF4.date2index"

When I write

```
cdf_time    = cdf_dataset.variables['time'][:]
```

attributes are not taken along. Here is a print output for this "cdf_time" version:

```
cdf_time is:  [ 56993.5  57023.   57052.5 ...,  91599.5  91630.   91660.5]
```

Which are basically the time values but with no attributes. Can anybody please explain to me what is the effect of this slicing "[:]? Why are the attributes not carried on?

Just by the way, I am pretty new on this so do not expect some neat piece of code, but I try to do my homework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you already answered the question yourself... `cdf_dataset.variables['time']` returns a NetCDF4 variable with attributes, add `[:]` and the return type is a Numpy array, which doesn't have the NetCDF variable attributes....

Comment: And how I usually deal with this: start with `bla=cdf_dataset.variables['time']` which gives you access to the attributes, and write `bla[:]` if you want to access the data.

Comment: Thanks Bart. Just the answer I was looking for. I did look around for a proper explanation but nowhere to be found. I believe this should go in the documentation of netCDF4 where it is also not to be found.